# How to exclude a commit from git pull request?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-pull

I have made a git pull request with my repo. Sometime later, before pull request got approved, I proceeded to make another commit&push which also got pushed up to pull request.

Is there a way to remove the last commit from pull request and how to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you simply can reset your branch to the previous commit, and force push: the pull request will be automatically updated.

```
git checkout yourBranch
git reset --hard yourBranch~
git push --force origin yourBranch
```

Then, if you want to make such an error harder, delete your branch locally: you won't checkout it or use it by mistake.