# Git: How can I jump back to a previous commit, thus undoing recent changes I've made?

Tags: git, git-commit

I've made 4 commits in my branch and pushed to Github. The last 3 of those commits contain changes that should not have been made. I want to 'jump back' to the first commit, removing all my un-wanted changes from the branch completely.

So far I have tried

```
git reset --hard 6b9b9baa6758598ca2ed48d5e029b4b5a2a7f194
```

and

```
git revert <SHA>
```

but these seem to do nothing - the unwanted changes remain in my pull request.

Does anyone know how I could go about this?

UPDATE: 
I need to go back to commit 6b9b9baa6758598ca2ed48d5e029b4b5a2a7f194. Log looks like:

```
commit 0a90687022fb458de36ac3ff3b3fd3f3920f6b0d
Author: Me
Date:   Thu May 31 10:04:36 2018 +1000

    Removed svg

commit 7dbcceb6e294572a531d84837753f5698bf192f6
Author: Me
Date:   Thu May 31 10:02:12 2018 +1000

    Removed icon from icons directory

commit 97cfd16c87ea280a4e6a7570272157e86195542e
Author: Me
Date:   Wed May 30 17:27:55 2018 +1000

     Added icons

commit 6b9b9baa6758598ca2ed48d5e029b4b5a2a7f194
Author: Me
Date:   Wed May 30 16:27:33 2018 +1000

    Updated css
```

Comment: Which revs are you using? In case of revert, you should use  the 3 new and unwanted commits. In case of reset, should use the commit you want to go.

Comment: I don't really know sorry - I just want to undo the changes in the 3 wrong commits altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude a commit from git pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963039/how-to-exclude-a-commit-from-git-pull-request)

Answer (score 0):

You need to push to Github after reset or revert.

To remove commits in the remote branch, you will need to push using force flag (*) after resetting.

Another option if to revert all 3 commits and push. Note that the bad commits will remain in the remote branch history.

(*) Not recommended if you do not know the consequences.

Comment: Hmm sounds easier just to close the pull request and start again

Comment: If that's an option, definitely better.

Comment: Really? That's surprising. I'm no expert (obviously) but I thought one of the powers of git was that it could allow you to revert code easily?

Comment: Force pushing own branch is OK, I doing it regularry without any problems. Use `push --force-with-lease` to be sure that noone changed the remote branch since your last fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push after reset or revert

1) in case of reset you need to push force (because you are changing remote history) as below:

```
git push origin <branch name> -f
```

2) in case of revert need simple push as below:

```
git push origin <branch name>
```

**It is always better to user revert** in place of reset.
As it will create extra(reverse) commits of your commit and it will not resetting history of git.